# How to retrieve specific columns rather than auto generate all columns or attributes from Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following entity relationships where I would like to get employee details from Employee class.

**Entity** code snippet

```
   @Entity
   public class Project
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
   private Employee empNumber;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "REQUESTED_BY", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
   private Employee requestedBy;
   }   

   @Entity
   public class Employee {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empNumber")
   private Set<Project> employees;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requestedBy")
   private Set<Project> employeeRequestedBy;
   }
```

**DAOImpl** code snippet

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Project> c = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
Root<Project> project = c.from(Project.class);
project.fetch(Project_.empNumber, JoinType.LEFT);
project.fetch(Project_.requestedBy, JoinType.LEFT);
c.orderBy(cb.desc(project.get("projectId")));
c.select(project);

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Project> projectCount = countQ.from(Project.class);
countQ.select(cb.count(projectCount));

List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if (projectId != null) {
ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class,
 "projectId");
Predicate predicate = cb.equal(project.get(Project_.projectId), pexp);
criteria.add(predicate);
            }

TypedQuery<Project> q =  entityManager.createQuery(c);
```

When I run my application, it generates the following sql query. Ideally I would like to have `designation` and `employee_dept` for `requested_by` attribute, however auto generated query generates `designation` and `employee_dept` for `emp_number` attribute as well, as it is shown in below query.

How can I specify to generate `designation` and `employee_dept` only for `requested_by` attribute? Any help is highly appreciable.

```
SELECT    *
      FROM    (SELECT project0_.project_id AS project1_2_0_,
                      employee1_.emp_number AS emp1_1_1_,
                      employee2_.emp_number AS emp1_1_2_,                            
                      project0_.date_requested AS date7_2_0_,
                      employee1_.employee_dept AS employee5_1_1_,
                      employee1_.designation AS designat6_1_1_,
                      employee1_.employee_name AS employee7_1_1_,
                      employee2_.employee_dept AS employee5_1_2_,
                      employee2_.designation AS designat6_1_2_,
                      employee2_.employee_name AS employee7_1_2_
                      FROM    projects project0_
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN employees employee1_
                      ON project0_.emp_number = employee1_.emp_number
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN employees employee2_
                      ON project0_.requested_by = employee2_.emp_number                            
                      ORDER BY    project0_.project_id DESC)
```

My expected query would be

```
SELECT    *
      FROM    (SELECT project0_.project_id AS project1_2_0_,
                      employee1_.emp_number AS emp1_1_1_,
                      employee2_.emp_number AS emp1_1_2_,                            
                      project0_.date_requested AS date7_2_0_,
                      employee1_.employee_name AS employee7_1_1_,
                      employee2_.employee_dept AS employee5_1_2_,
                      employee2_.designation AS designat6_1_2_,
                      employee2_.employee_name AS employee7_1_2_
                      FROM    projects project0_
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN employees employee1_
                      ON project0_.emp_number = employee1_.emp_number
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN employees employee2_
                      ON project0_.requested_by = employee2_.emp_number                            
                      ORDER BY    project0_.project_id DESC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling JPA to fetch Project and its referenced Employees, so it needs to return complete entities otherwise it corrupts the context.  I don't know how/if Hibernate supports lazy basic mappings, but that might be one option - mark the attributes in Employee that you don't always want as lazy.  This will affect both requestedBy and empNumber relationships equally though.

If you do not want complete Employee data, you might have the query return only the data you want.  Leave the query to fetch the empNumber but make the requestedBy relationship lazy, and have the query return Project and the Project_.requestedBy data that you want.  Linda has a great example of using multiselect to return data at https://blogs.oracle.com/ldemichiel/entry/the_typing_of_criteria_queries .

Comment: Chris I will go through the link even though I am not very sure about Lazy approach though. And I do not know why this question has been down voted. :-)